# Remember previous utterance

Tags: bixby

I have a capsule where the user needs to provide Bixby an account name, property, and date range, then Bixby returns the result. What if the user wanted to check a different account with the same property and date range and the user's utterance is something like "What about the foo account?" How could I get Bixby to keep the property and date range from the previous utterance, but change the account name to search for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the language training, you can define a continuation of the goal.  That will allow you to filter on 'foo' in your action.

[image]

For example:
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/training.intro-training

Comment: This explanation helped me a lot! In my situation I used the same goal as the continuation and all the previous parameters passed through with the updated account name.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Bixby will use the conversation history to attempt to provide inputs that have not been defined by the user.

This means that, if the goal Action for your utterance "What about the foo account?" requires the property and date range inputs, Bixby will assume them from the conversation history if any exist.

Comment: Is there any property to disable such a default behavior?

Comment: Yes, you can define the `transient` feature in any Concepts that you don't want to be carried in history. You can learn more about it in our documentation here. https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/text.features.transient